# How can create a table dinamically in springboot?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

First of all, apologize for the grammatical errors that you can make. My English is not very good.

Is possible create a Table dinamically passing name of table, info that should be rows???

I receive data from [geojson](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson), and each row should be each property that exists in each Feature.

Each geojson could have differents properties so, thats the reason why would create tables dinamically and associate with an existing table created with an Entity.

constructor(String name, String[] nameColumns, Object[] data)

```
| id |   property    |    geometry     |
----------------------------------------
| 0  | data.property | data.geometry   |


protected Scheme createScheme(final String creatorId, final String name, final String description, final InputStream inputStream) { 

        DeserializeJSONFile desJsonFile = new DeserializeJSONFile();
        desJsonFile.init(inputStream);

        List<String> geometries = desJsonFile.loadGeometries();
        List<String> properties = desJsonFile.loadProperties();

        String nameTable = CreateTable(nameTable, properties, geomerties);

        Scheme scheme = new Scheme();
        scheme.setCreator(creatorId);
        scheme.setName(name);
        scheme.setDescription(description);
        scheme.setTable(nameTable);
        createScheme(scheme);
        return scheme;
    }
```

%nameTable% is a param.

```
create table %nameTable% (  %nameTable% varchar(255),
    table_id int8 not null auto_increment,
    properties jsonb not null,
    geometry jsonb not null,
    primary key (name_table) );
```

Comment: If you add more details on _why_ you want to do this, there could be some hints on ways to avoid it all together.

Comment: You could create the tables dynamically, sure - just execute `CREATE TABLE` native query. The problem is you want to also construct and use entities dynamically via hibernate. I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Maybe I dont understand me or I dont undertand you.... 
1 - Can I create a table via native query and insert rows??? 
2 - Once the table is created, can I associate them??